# Migrate to java11

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, module, java-11

I have a big gradle project with a lot of gradle modules.

I want to add java11 support with back compatibility (with java 8).

1) Do I have to use java9 modules system, or such migration is possible without it ?

2) If yes, can I auto-generate module-info files automatically, my project is huge.

Comment: It is completely possible, please follow: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html.

Comment: *Do I have to use java9 modules system, or such migration is possible without it ?* => If you meant without the introduction of module descriptors in your code. Yes that's possible... *can I auto-generate module-info files automatically* => yes, but only if you decide to migrate to developing a modular application, should you do this.

Comment: I have some third-party library which is not java-9 compatible and without AutoModuleName tag in Manifest.

Application wants to access from java.base module to the jar's classes => error.

What is the easiest way to resolve it ? Can I make this jar a named module ?

Answer (score 0):

If not defined otherwise all you classes will be packed into a unnamed module.
But you should be able to run your app without code modifications.